# Blank page for Vuejs app on Android WebView

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, android-webview

This issue is reproducible:

1. Install the latest version of npm and vue-cli
2. Generate a simple vue app with “vue create newapp” (babel v3, vuex, router)
3. Load that app inside an Android WebView (HTTPS setup assumed)
4. The WebView shows a blank page instead of the Hello World/Welcome to VueJs text

How to get vuejs compatible to Android WebView running Chrome 61?

And I get no errros in "window.onerror()" after adding it to the head of index.html

Comment: I have found the solution: It was only a caching issue that involes intermediaries.

Comment: i suggest you post your answer in the answer section so that other people who might be stuck, find it useful

Comment: @ChillyCode - I have a similar issue. Can you please expand on your answer?  Thanks :)